Azure Pipelines - resource reference
I have a complex pipeline that is used by several projects for integration testing. It defines resources in the root Yaml and, in most cases uses 'checkout' to checkout the relevant repo to the test agent where it is then copied to the test host and installed. However for one project this approach adds 20 - 30 minutes due to the repo size and a decision was made to pass the relevant branch info to the test host and do a git pull from there instead.
All was working fine, however it was noticed that there were 2 fields where the branch info was being entered which was causing confusion. The first, which was the standard resource definition dialog was being ignored and the information was being entered from a manually-entered text field instead. As this could lead to errors, a change was implemented to remove the text field and pass the branch of the resource selected instead. However, trying to reference that is proving problematic
The following is a sanitised version of the root yaml:
parameters:
  - name: resourceTypes
  ...
  - name: deployEXE
  ...

trigger: ...

resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: ...
  repositories:
  - repository: TestData
    type: git
    name: testdata
    ref: refs/heads/master



extends:
  template: pipeline-template.yml
  parameters:
    jobName: 'Nightly Testing'
    testHost: 'VM Name'
    testTask: '.'
    deployExe: ${{parameters.deployExe}}
    checkoutTemplate: checkout-steps.yml
    postTestTemplate: post-test-steps.yml
    agentPool: test-agents
    agentName: VTMAGENT
    usesTemplate:
      repositories:
       - TestData
    hasOtherOutput: true
    timeoutInMinutes: 180
    additionalData: 
      - ${{parameters.resourceTypes}}
      - ${{resources.repositories.TestData.ref}}

The bottom line is the issue.
Referencing the repo using double brackets ${{resources.repositories.TestData.ref}} generates an error that resources is an unknown name
Referencing using single bracket $(resources.repositories.TestData.ref) passes that as a literal string so the git pull tries to pull a branch called $(resources.repositories.TestData.ref)
Is it possible to reference the repo information and pass it to the template?

Have you tried ${{ resources('repositories.TestData.ref') }}? I know of problems with . in variable names similar to this.

@kuga Thanks but this raised the "Unrecognized value: 'resources'." error

@MikeWorsley, You need to define a variable and use the variable for the template parameter. You can find the usage on the doc resources.repositories.repository variables. Also make sure object type parameter defined in template to receive the value, i added the details below, thanks.

The metadata for a repository resource is available to all jobs in the form of runtime variables.
Instead of:
additionalData: 
  - ${{parameters.resourceTypes}}
  - ${{resources.repositories.TestData.ref}}

Try
additionalData: 
  - ${{parameters.resourceTypes}}
  - $[ resources.repositories.TestData.ref ]

Or, as an alternative:
variables:
  ref: $[ resources.repositories.TestData.ref ]

# .....
additionalData: 
  - ${{ parameters.resourceTypes }}
  - $(ref)


See resources.repositories.repository definition and Understand variable syntax

Thanks but this just passed in the '$[ resources.repositories.TestData.ref ]' as a literal string

@MikeWorsley try declaring a variable first, as in my second example.

The 2nd example from @RuiJarimba is correct. You need to define a variable and use the variable for the template parameter. You can find the usage on the doc resources.repositories.repository variables.
In addition, on the template yaml, you need to define object type parameter since you have two values with - in main yaml. You can check each element value with a separate echo command.
template yaml:
parameters:
  - name: jobName
    type: string
    default: 'job1'
  .....

  - name: additionalData
    type: object
    default: []

jobs:
- job: job1
  steps:
  - ${{ each data in parameters.additionalData }}:
    - script: echo ${{ data }}


